# What scene in Full Metal Jacket was the "Ann-Margret" joke in Netflix "The Punisher" referencing?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, full-metal-jacket, the-punisher-tv

In the Netflix *"The Punisher"* series, during the debriefing for the "Operation Cerberus" one of guys (after hearing typical "you are one team now serving me" stuff) wisecracks:

> So, does this mean [Ann-Margret's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ann-Margret) not coming?

After which many soldiers start laughing and calling him an idiot.

This sentence, according to the [TvTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/ThePunisher2017?from=Series.ThePunisher) page is a reference to the "Full metal Jacket", but its been a while since I've seen it - in what circumstances those words are spoken in the original FMJ movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a morning meeting of the "Stars and Stripes" newspaper staff the day after the Tet Offensive began, the editor, Lt. Lockhart, gives a downbeat briefing about how badly things have gone. When he's done, Joker cynically asks if Ann Margaret is still coming to do a USO show, making fun of how oblivious the Army General Staff is about how everything in Vietnam is going.

> "[So, does this mean Ann-Margret's not coming?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpO0OV4mfvo)" » scene from "Full Metal Jacket" on YouTube.

The reference to the FMJ quote in "The Punisher" is used the same way, to mock the oblivious Pollyanna nature of their leadership.

Comment: I would argue that in The Punisher, it's not so much mocking the leadership, but rather that the soldier in question is mocking _himself_ for (supposedly) failing to understand the serious nature of the operation. He's actively referencing FMJ (that's not just OOU) and subverting its original context.

Comment: Hmmmmnnn. Will have to take another look.